# Reset password link yields Access Denied in Firefox

Tags: users

Our site is D6. Our users are having problems with the password reset/account verification function and it appears it currently appears to happen only in Firefox.

User applies for an account or asks for a password reset. They receive an email with a link to a one-time 24-hour password. They click the link and get a Password Reset page and a button to log in. When they press the login button, they get ACCESS DENIED.

This works fine in Safari and Chrome. It appears to be a Firefox issue (though truthfully this has been an on-again, off-again problem for years with Drupal no matter the version.)

We have explored a variety of drupal.org forum suggestions including commenting out the $cookie_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; in settings.php file ... or NOT commenting out that line and putting in $cookie_domain = "www.sitedomain.org"; or $cookie_domain = '.sitedomain.org'; ...

We also notice that in Firefox you can't seem to log out; you have to close Firefox to end the session. I bring this issue up because it appears related -- and it only happens in Firefox.

Your help would be ENORMOUSLY appreciated. This really hurts us and we can't figure it out.

thanks in advance.

(ALSO, if you could, we would love to know what your DRAFT set up was. It's great)

geoff

Comment: Does FF in private browsing work?  Have you disabled all FF plugins?

Comment: We will test with FF in private browsing and will post our findings. We will also test with all FF plugins disabled.